# TableLayout cell size

Tags: java, android, xml, tablelayout

I have made a TableLayout and it basically looks like this:

[image]

Problem is, that there is too much space between the ":" and the numbers and sometimes the number wont fit in the screen.

I want to make the cell with the string ("azimuth" for example) to be smaller.

Is there someway to do this?
The code looks like this (first row for example):

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="bennybegun.measuringapp.MainActivity">

<TableRow
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:text="Angles Table"
        android:gravity="center"></TextView>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"></TextView>

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:text="Azimuth: "
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rotationx"
        android:text="X...."
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif"></TextView>


</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify width attributes for your textviews;

```
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="bennybegun.measuringapp.MainActivity">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:textSize="35dp"
            android:text="Angles Table"
            android:gravity="center"></TextView>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!--In your case you know the titles beforehand so you can fix the width-->
        <TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Azimuth: "
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>

        <TextView
android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/rotationx"
            android:text="X...."
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_weight="1"
            android:typeface="serif"></TextView>


    </TableRow>
```

With this method the values side is supposed to consume all the remaining space. Check to see if you can let the values span more columns than the titles

Comment: This solution makes everything to fit in the screen by making the number to be like 2 rows. I try to make it all fit in 1 row.

Comment: try using a  negative value for margin for the values column, I haven't tried it for horizontal layouts but it works for me in vertical layouts, try marginLeft or marginStart